# What is the corresponding value of the system default backlog value at java http server?

Tags: java, backlog

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html

backlog - the socket backlog. If this value is less than or equal to zero, then a system default value is used.

what is corresponding valueof system default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is operating system dependent.  And for some operating systems, it is a setting that can be configured by the system administrators.

For example, `man 2 listen` for Linux [says](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html):

> Since Linux 5.4, the default in this file is 4096; in earlier kernels, the default value is 128.  In kernels before 2.4.25, this limit was a hard coded value, `SOMAXCONN`, with the value 128.

By contrast, on Windows the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen) of the `backlog` parameter says:

> The maximum length of the queue of pending connections. If set to `SOMAXCONN`, the underlying service provider responsible for sockets will set the backlog to a maximum reasonable value.